# Android SoundPool sound playback intermittent

Tags: android, soundpool

I have several `GridView` items that play a small .ogg file when they are selected. They are played using the `SoundPool` class, however this class seems very intermittent - sometimes the sound plays, sometimes it doesn't; there is no pattern to this so I am having trouble figuring out why it's doing it.

Here is my code:

```
public void playSelectionSound(){
        SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        int soundId = sp.load(this, R.raw.char_select, 1);
        sp.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually resorted to switching to MediaPlayer instead of SoundPool:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.char_select); //open media player
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
        mp.start(); //play the sound
```

Works everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to play it immediately after the load since the load can take time. Instead, you should use SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() and play it in that callback. Here you can be sure that soundpool has loaded successfully.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide me with an example please?

Comment: I have tried this using `.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                                       int status) {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });` and then playing the sound after but it's still not working properly